# Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Method not found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a coded ui test from MTM:

> Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestUtilities.AddAssemblyResolveHandler()'..

All I'm looking for is a hint as to why this is happening, my project references look like this:

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, The Test Controller and Agent too are 2013 Update 4.

I can queue a build, but when I try and run a test against the build using MTM, I get this error.

EDIT, Also using net 4.5.1.

EDIT 2: Everything runs locally in dev environment when tests are kicked off from Visual Studio. It's once I kick off the tests through MTM -> Controller -> Agent where the problem persists. The exact same message is thrown regardless of the test.

Comment: Is your test cases associated with the a test case that is part of the build used? Since it's working in VS, the only difference is in your build.

Comment: What I did was copy over dll's to the build drop folder. Same result.

Comment: Just found this, could be similar but they say it's fixed in update 4 that you seem to already have. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/893888/ui-test-fails-after-vs-2013-update-2-install

Comment: Also, is your MTM, Controller and Agent all on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the test run has all the necessary dlls in the test run directory, in the machine where test controller runs check the directory
"C:\Users\ *username* \appdata\Local\VSEQT\QTController\ *testrunid* \Deployment\"